# R pop-up boxes not working when run in terminal

Tags: r, popup, zenity

I am using the svDialogs (an R wrapper library for zenity) to create GUI pop-up boxes, and this works fine when I run the code through either R studio, or from an R terminal session (running Ubuntu 16.04).

A minimal example is:

```
library(svDialogs)
dlgMessage("Hello Stackoverflow!")
```

However, when I run the code directly through the terminal it does not work:

```
Rscript --vanilla -e 'source("path/to/file.R")'
```

The terminal shows that the library loaded, and does not display an error message: but the pop-up does not appear! If I add an additional line after the call to dlgMessage, that line runs. i.e. if I run the modified code

```
library(svDialogs)
dlgMessage("Hello Stackoverflow!")
print("Goodbye Stackoverflow!")
```

then the second line does show in the terminal window (i.e. the code is not crashing at dlgMessage).

Happy for solutions not relying on dlgMessage if there is a workarond: I'd previously tried using Zenity natively through R using system() but couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R can be run in either interactive or non-interactive modes, with the default depending on whether or not it is assumed that there is a human operator, see documentation for [interactive](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/interactive.html).

When run in non-interactive mode, R will not display any pop-up boxes. The default is that when running code in the terminal, R runs in non-interactive mode. Following the documentation above, this can be overwritten by using the command in linux

```
R --vanilla --interactive < "path/to/file.R"
```

Similarly in Windows using `--ess` with `Rterm.exe`